# android remove prefix namespaces from xml file

Tags: android, xml, namespaces

I'm doing a parse xml in android and I want to remove the namespace prefixes on all elements.
for example in the xml below I want to remove the prefix "ns4"

```
<ns4:profiles >
    <ns4:list-users>
        <ns4:user>

        </ns4:user>
        <ns4:user>

        </ns4:user>
    </ns4:list-users>
</ns4:profiles>
```

How can I remove the prefixes?